# Java WebSocket with background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket

I'm new to Java & i need help on the following issue:

I'm start learning how a websocket app works. My code uses javax.websocket to implement websocket server which convert a POJO to websocket listener as below:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/sample")
public class SampleSocket {
    private static Set<Session> clients = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // handle connection open here
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        // handle connection close here
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session) {
        // handle incoming message here
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session) {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```

Above code works.

Now, I want to create a new background thread to do some preparations before the server enter listening mode and/or keep track of some other info. But I have no idea how instantiate this background thread. SampleSocket constructor seems not to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PostConstruct will help this this situation.